# Iterate and compare all values within keys in a dict. Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionnarysuch as :

```
dict = {'group1':["-----AGAAC--C--","-----ATATA-----"],'group2':["------AGGCGGA----","--AAACC----------","--AAACCG---------"]}
```

, in this dictionnary I would like to compare all values with each other by iterate all of them.
The idea is to compare each value and count when a letter is in front of a nonalpha character.

Here are the results I should get (the number of letter with in front of it a nonalpha character (characterised by the `pipe` in the below exemple) / length of the string )

### group1:

element1 vs element2

```
-----AGAAC--C--
-----*****--|--
-----ATATA-----
1/15 = 0.07
```

### group2:

element 1 vs element2

```
------AGGCGGA----
--||||*||||||----
--AAACC----------
10/17= 0.59
```

element 2 vs element 3

```
--AAACC----------
--*****|---------
--AAACCG---------
1/17= 0.059
```

element 1 vs element 3

```
------AGGCGGA----
--||||**|||||----
--AAACCG---------
9/17=0.53
```

Here is a code I use to compare them an calculate a score for the group1:

```
value1="-----AGAAC--C--"
value2="-----ATATA-----"

count=0
for a,b in zip(value1,value2):
    print(a.isalpha(),b.isalpha())
    if a.isalpha() == True and b.isalpha()==False:
        count += 1
    if a.isalpha()==False and b.isalpha()== True :
        count +=1

print(count/len(value1))
```

but I cannot manage to do it for all value automaticaly... Does anyone have an idea? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do that:

```
from itertools import combinations

# Input data
dict = {
    'group1': ['-----AGAAC--C--', '-----ATATA-----'],
    'group2': ['------AGGCGGA----', '--AAACC----------', '--AAACCG---------']
}

# Iterate groups
for group, elements in dict.items():
    # Print group name
    print(group)
    # Iterate every pair of elements
    for element1, element2 in combinations(elements, 2):
        # Check both elements have the same length
        n = len(element1)
        if len(element2) != n:
            raise ValueError
        # Count the number of times character types do not match
        count = sum(c1.isalpha() != c2.isalpha() for c1, c2 in zip(element1, element2))
        # Compute ratio
        ratio = count / n
        # Print result
        print(f'    * {element1} vs {element2}: {ratio:.4f} ({count}/{n})')
    print()
```

Output:

```
group1
    * -----AGAAC--C-- vs -----ATATA-----: 0.0667 (1/15)

group2
    * ------AGGCGGA---- vs --AAACC----------: 0.5882 (10/17)
    * ------AGGCGGA---- vs --AAACCG---------: 0.5294 (9/17)
    * --AAACC---------- vs --AAACCG---------: 0.0588 (1/17)
```

EDIT: If you want to collect the list of pairs that produce a score above some threshold you can modify the code above slightly:

```
from itertools import combinations

dict = {
    'group1': ['-----AGAAC--C--', '-----ATATA-----'],
    'group2': ['------AGGCGGA----', '--AAACC----------', '--AAACCG---------']
}
threshold = 0.10

interesting_pairs = []
for group, elements in dict.items():
    for element1, element2 in combinations(elements, 2):
        n = len(element1)
        if len(element2) != n:
            raise ValueError
        count = sum(c1.isalpha() != c2.isalpha() for c1, c2 in zip(element1, element2))
        ratio = count / n
        if ratio > threshold:
            interesting_pairs.append((element1, element2))

print(interesting_pairs)
# [('------AGGCGGA----', '--AAACC----------'), ('------AGGCGGA----', '--AAACCG---------')]
```

EDIT 2: Following the discussion in the comments, here is yet another variation that groups together elements with a ratio over some threshold, transitively. This is actually another different problem on its own, namely finding the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of the graph given by that relationship. You can do that with for example a depth-first search:

```
from itertools import combinations

dict = {
    'group1': ['-----AGAAC--C--', '-----ATATA-----'],
    'group2': ['------AGGCGGA----', '--AAACC----------', '--AAACCG---------']
}
threshold = 0.10

# Find connected elements
connected = {}
for group, elements in dict.items():
    for element1, element2 in combinations(elements, 2):
        n = len(element1)
        if len(element2) != n:
            raise ValueError
        count = sum(c1.isalpha() != c2.isalpha() for c1, c2 in zip(element1, element2))
        ratio = count / n
        if ratio > threshold:
            connected.setdefault(element1, {element1}).add(element2)
            connected.setdefault(element2, {element2}).add(element1)

# Search components with DFS
result = []
visited = set()
for elem, conn in  connected.items():
    if elem in visited:
        continue
    visited.add(elem)
    conn = set(conn)
    pending = list(conn)
    while pending:
        subelem = pending.pop()
        if subelem in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(subelem)
        subconn = connected[subelem]
        conn.update(subconn)
        pending.extend(subconn)
    result.append(conn)
print(result)
# [{'------AGGCGGA----', '--AAACCG---------', '--AAACC----------'}]
```

Comment: Whoo thank you I did not expect something like that. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Have you an idea how could I put for instance all element that have a ratio > 0.10 in a new list of list together ? for instance put `------AGGCGGA----` , `--AAACC----------` and `--AAACCG--------- `together in a list such (and the same for group1) as : `list1 = [["------AGGCGGA----" , "--AAACC----------", "--AAACCG---------"],["-----AGAAC--C--","-----ATATA----"]`

Comment: @chippycentra I'm not sure I get what you mean, the `list1` you have defined contains all the elements in `group2` and `group1`.

Comment: Ho sorry, in fact I would like to create a new list and within this list create a list of pairs of sequences that have a ratio `> 0.10`. So here in this exemple if the ratio between `------AGGCGGA---- vs --AAACCG---------` becomes `0.005` instead of `0.5294` and `-----AGAAC--C-- vs -----ATATA-----` becomes `0.5` instead of `0.0667` I should get a list such as: `list1 = [["------AGGCGGA----" , "--AAACC----------"],"[-----AGAAC--C--","-----ATATA-----"]]` but in the real exemple I should get : `list1 = [["------AGGCGGA----" , "--AAACC----------", "--AAACCG---------"]]`

Comment: @chippycentra I have added a variation in the solution, I'm not sure if that is what you were after.

Comment: Yep in fact it is not a list of pairs, I made a mistake because in this exemple `["------AGGCGGA----" , "--AAACC----------", "--AAACCG---------"]` are in the same sub list because `------AGGCGGA---- vs --AAACC----------` > `0.10` and `------AGGCGGA---- vs --AAACCG---------` > `0.10` too.

Comment: @chippycentra But `--AAACC---------- vs --AAACCG---------` < `0.10` so shouldn't those two _not_ be in the same sublist?

Comment: Yes but because both have a ratio > 0.10  with ------AGGCGGA---- , then they are in the same list :)

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much for your help and all the time you spent to help.